# What abstraction should one use for read-modify-writes operations in ARM code

Tags: c, arm, portability, atomic

Many ARM processors include special features that allow for various forms of read-modify-write operations on I/O and/or RAM.  It seems, however, that no single approach will work consistently across the spectrum of Cortex-M3 and Cortex-M0 devices.

When I was targeting Cortex-M3 devices, I wrote a few methods like `MaskedSet32(uint32_t *target, uint32_t mask, uint32_t newval)` which would use load-linked/compare-exclusive to atomically modify part of a 32-bit number in interrupt-safe fashion.  The Cortex M0 doesn't offer those instructions, however.  I could perhaps have code save the interrupt state, disable interrupts, perform a read-modify-write, and re-enable interrupts, but that seems a bit clunky.  Some Cortex processors offer bit-banding or other features so that a single atomic memory operation can be used to do things like atomically set a single bit, but different processors seem to do things differently.  Further, I'm not sure what abstraction would allow the best degree of portability.

For things in RAM, my guess would be that when speed isn't critical the best approach would be to have subroutines for things like `MaskedSet32`, `Increment`, `BottomPegI32` (atomic version of `*dest = (*dest < limit) ? limit : *dest;`).  Such an approach could be used with I/O as well, but it would seem a shame not to take advantage of some of the specialized hardware that some processors offer to make such things more efficient.  For example, the Freescale KL-25 could perform an operation like:

```
MaskedSet32(&IOWhatever, 0x0F00, 0x0500); // Update bits 8-11 with a value of 0101
```

by writing a value of 5 to a certain I/O address.  It would seem wasteful to load an I/O address and two other parameters and then call a subroutine to accomplish what could be done by loading an I/O address and a constant `5` and performing a single memory store.

Although a lot of demo code I see for processors just uses ordinary Boolean operators, I find distasteful the idea of doing

```
IoWhatever = (IoWhatever & ~0x0F00) | 0x0500;
```

in any situation where an interrupt might want to write to one part of an I/O address while main-line code is writing another.  Using atomic operations as a matter of common practice would seem like a safer approach, but I'd like to do so in such fashion as to bog down the code as little as possible.

Should I define a SetIoBitField macro which takes an address (that would be cast to `uint32_t*`), field offset, field width, and new data, requiring that the field offset and width be constant, and then either uses an atomic read-modify-write method (with a mask pre-computed based on the constants), an in-line load-linked/store-exclusive loop (likewise), or a write to the a processor-specific special I/O space, or should I define and use such a macro only on processors that have such a primitive and use MaskedSet32 on others [figuring that I/O bit assignments on processors without the bitfield support are apt to be different anyway], or what approach would seem clearest and most portable?

Comment: Are you writing code to run on bare metal, or on an underlying operating system?

Comment: @R..: Bare metal currently, though I might like to try to use the Keil RTX at some point.

Answer (score 2):

The standard and obvious approach is to write the code so that it conditionally compiles according to the ARM generation number:

```
#if ARM_GEN >= 3
   (use advanced ARM primitives)
#else
   (use clunkier ways to accomplish the same things)
#endif
```

where `ARM_GEN` is defined by the build.  If the code base will be worked on by people not closely communicated to, it is not a bad idea to provide a compile time warning or error if the symbol is not defined:

```
#ifndef ARM_GEN
 #error Define ARM_GEN as 1, 2, 3, ... 9 of the ARM architecture (ARM3, ARM9, etc.)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Using preprocessor to choose implementation is a good approach to solve the issue. Still, in this case, disabling/enabling interrupts may not be the best design pattern to handle the concurrency issue.

As you are realizing, not every MCU will give you support to perform masked write in an atomic manner, also, using this specific support would make unportable code. As a firmware designer I like to use standardized patterns, so, if it is really impossible to remove the concurrency on the same memory address of your system, you should use mutexes and/or FIFOs.

I believe you can change the layout of your system to avoid concurrency. Memory concurrency is totally unnecessary since modern chips has lots of bytes for a low cost. IO port concurrency is a very common problem and most of the MCU manufactures implement hardware support to set (or clear) a single port bit without having to read the IO status, removing the need of software concurrency handling.

Comment: I like to use consistent patterns too.  Mutexes don't spontaneously exist--they must be built from some kind of primitive.  Further, it's not really possible to use a mutex directly within an interrupt handler; one must instead have interrupt schedule some code to run, and then use the mutex within that code.  Not impossible, but a lot of extra overhead and complexity to add for what might otherwise be a very simple interrupt handler.

Comment: Every machine I've examined makes it possible for a single write operation to switch any particular single I/O port from driving high to driving low or vice versa (though they're not implemented in any particular consistent way).  Sometimes, though, it's necessary to switch ports between input and output modes, however, and many controllers offer no primitive for that.  I wish controller designers would consider concurrency issues when designing their register layouts; some are really horrible.

Comment: @supercat it's true that conventional mutex doesn't work on interruptions. It is necessary a modified mutex approach for interruptions.

Comment: What sort of "modified mutex"?  And if e.g. one interrupt requires switching bit 3 of PORTA from floating to active, and another requires switching bit 4, how could one use a mutex-ish anything without adding complicating dependencies between the two otherwise-independent interrupts?

Comment: Modified mutex consist of aborting an interruption or queuing it to later, it's not always feasible, depends if your interruption process more data. In your design only the lowest priority interruption will be interrupted, so, the highest priority interruption should not process, or queue it to later, when the other priority is processing. Or, you could disable the highest interruption to trigger at the critical point.

Comment: I think you should disable the highest interruption to trigger at the critical point. I don't like this approach, but sometimes we are married to legacy code and we must live with it. hehe

Comment: Even in new code, I don't see any practical way either interrupt could safely allow the other to execute between the read and the write, and allowing for an interrupt to defer its operation would seem to yield worse interrupt-response time than simply having each interrupt grab the global-interrupt-enable flag, disable all interrupts, perform the operation, and restore the global-interrupt-enable flag.

Comment: @fanl: btw, the correct term is "interrupt", not "interruption".